# Copying and loading a page's full HTML onto another page

Tags: php, html

My current overall goal is to have page B, which is a blank page, load the content from page A, which is updated many times during any given day. I don't control when page A's content is updated but the idea is that page B will be a test page on our server that we can work with in real time since it will always have the current HTML of the original page.

So to put this much more simply. Let's say every time `foo.com` was loaded, you could go to `foo.com/morefoo` and it would always look exactly the same as the home page `foo.com`

I'm not looking for instant solutions but more suggestions on the best routes to go with this because I am going circles in my head wondering which way is the best to attack this. My first thoughts have been to have page A load and save the HTML to a file (I don't believe this can be accomplished with `jQuery` and would have to be `PHP`), and then page B load it using `include()`. But I don't know if it's going to be an issue having the page that is clicked millions of times a day to save (and overwrite) text to a single file every single time the page loads.

Comment: try with a cURL request for the data (from Page A) upon page B load. This would be a PHP solution

Comment: "*millions of times a day*" really?

Comment: @Martin I was not feeling very good writing that part. Since I'm still getting my feet wet with computer science, I wasn't completely certain if the level of activity of the original page would impact the way it would be best to go about that first idea I had.

Comment: Research Curl as that is a PHP solution for having your server grabbing one page from the web and then displaying and/or editing it and outputting it as page B.

Comment: `Echo File_get_contents("http://www.foo.com/foofoo.php");` http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Comment: Keep in mind if the owner of the page you are pulling data from is in a bad mood he can ban the ip of your domain

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://foo.com'); //Get page contents
file_put_contents('morefoo.html', $html); //Save page contents to file
```

Then you have copied the entire rendered page to a new HTML file. If the stylesheets and javascript files are included with an absolute URL in the original page, then you will probably have no problems getting the copied page to work and look like the original. But if there are relatives paths set in the HTML you have to parse the page and replace the relative paths with absolute paths. For this you would check out http://php.net/manual/de/function.preg-replace.php

But you wouldn't copy the contents everytime foo.com is loaded. This makes everything slow. You would set up a cronjob to update the morefoo.html every hour or so.

Comment: There is no need to make it that complex unless you want to cache the data. A `echo file_get_contents();` will be enough to output the source file in the requesting php file

Comment: You did not suggest regex to parse html did you??

Comment: I recommended regex to replace relative urls with absolute urls. What would be a better solution?